# A fast growing functions in $\sf{ACA_0}$ and $\sf{Z_2}$

Tags: formal-proofs, second-order-logic

There is a fast growing function whose totality is not provable in a subsystem of second order arithmetic called $\sf{ACA_0}$: the Paris-Harrington function. I would like to know the name (and the definition) of a cousin of it for the system $\sf{Z_2}.$

Comment: Since ordinal analysis is currently stuck around $\Pi^1_2$-$\mathsf{CA_0}$, a tiny fragment of $\mathsf{Z_2}$, I doubt a good analogue is known at present. (Of course we can whip up trivial examples, such as "let $f(i)$ be the value on input $i$ of the $i$th $\mathsf{Z}_2$-provably-total recursive function," but that's presumably "cheating" - even if it's a bit difficult to pin down exactly what *isn't* cheating.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I remeber something called the `Hydra game` from set theory: is it of a good use here ?